# How to handle the Maybe output of a function?

Tags: haskell

I've been browsing for solutions for an hour now but I just can't figure this out!
If a function has `Maybe` as its output, how would I make a construction similar to `if-else` in imperative programming?

I am trying to use [`elemIndex`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/elemIndex_f.html). If the item is present in the list, I want to do A (with the item). If the item is not present, I want to do B. What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

```
-- Search for the number 10 in a list of integers and return the information as a string   
testFunction :: [Int] -> String
testFunction numbers = elemIndex 10 numbers
-- If 10 is present, return "Index is " ++ show index
-- If 10 is not present, return "Not present"
```

In most of my attempts I'll run into an error such as:

```
Couldn't match type `Maybe Int' with `Int'
```

(I know it's something with `Just` and `Nothing` - I just can't find or figure out the syntax.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using a [case expression](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) (see section 4.3) to pattern match?

```hs
testFunction :: [Int] -> String
testFunction numbers = case elemIndex 10 numbers of
  Just idx -> "Index is " ++ show idx
  Nothing -> "Not present"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `maybe` function encapsulates the pattern-matching on a `Maybe a` value to handle both `Nothing` and `Just x` values. The first argument is a replacement for `Nothing`; the second is a function that gets applied to the wrapped value in a `Just x`.

```
> import Data.Char (toUpper)
> maybe "foo" (map toUpper) Nothing
"foo"
> maybe "foo" (map toUpper) (Just "bar")
"BAR"
```

For your use case,

```
testFunction numbers = maybe 
                          "Not present"
                          (\x -> "Index is " ++ show x)
                          (elemIndex 10 numbers)
-- In point-free form,
-- testFunction = maybe "Not present" (("Index is " ++) . show) . elemIndex 10
```